# Looping cosine similarity formula from one dataframe to another dataframe using pandas & BERT

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, bert-language-model, cosine-similarity

I am building a NLP project which compares sentence similarities between two different dataframes. Here is an example of the dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Element Detail':['Too many competitors in market', 'Highly skilled employees']})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Element Details':['Our workers have a lot of talent', 
                                      'this too is a sentence',
                                      'this is very different',
                                      'another sentence is this',
                                      'not much of anything']
                    })
```

I currently have the code set up in a way that it compares the first cell in df with all the cells in df1. It then picks the highest cosine similarity score and puts that in a separate dataframe with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

model_name = 'bert-base-nli-mean-tokens'
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer(model_name)
sentence_vecs = model.encode(df['Element Detail'])
sentence_vecs1 = model.encode(df1['Element Details'])

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

new = cosine_similarity(
    [sentence_vecs[0]],
    sentence_vecs1[0:]
)

d = pd.DataFrame(new)
T =pd.DataFrame.transpose(d)
df_new = T.insert(0, 'New_ID', range(1, 1 + len(T)))
Tnew = (T.add_prefix('X'))
Final = (Tnew[Tnew.X0 == Tnew.X0.max()])
```

The end product is this dataframe:

```
    XNew_ID     X0  
0   1           0.615005
```

How can I write a piece of code so it will loop through the rest of the elements in df and write the to the 'Final' dataframe in the same manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosign similarity can perform well on two lists, so you can pass the whole embeddings list as arguments and extract maximum similarities afterward.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

model_name = 'bert-base-nli-mean-tokens'
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer(model_name)
sentence_vecs = model.encode(df1['Element Detail'])
sentence_vecs1 = model.encode(df2['Element Details'])

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

new = cosine_similarity(
    sentence_vecs,
    sentence_vecs1
)
max_similarities = np.amax(new, axis=1)
d = pd.DataFrame(new)
T =pd.DataFrame.transpose(d)
df_new = T.insert(0, 'New_ID', range(1, 1 + len(T)))
Tnew = (T.add_prefix('X'))
Final = (Tnew[Tnew.X0 == Tnew.X0.max()])
Final
```

output:

```
    XNew_ID     X0          X1
0   1           0.615005    0.868932
```